# Java getting absolute path from directory count list

Tags: java, file

Expected:
find the number files in the folder, and collect the absolute path for each file in the directory.

```
File certificatePath = new File("resources/NPL");
 String absolutePath = certificatePath.getAbsolutePath();
 File directory = new File(absolutePath);
 int fileCount=directory.list().length;
```

From the above code getting the no of files in folder (resources/NPL), now i'm struggle to get the absolute path for the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`listFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) instead fo `list()` (provided you have the security rights to do so), otherwise you are stuck with the file names.

Comment: even with file names he already has his `absolutePath`. What about `Paths.get(absolutePath, fileName).toString();`

Comment: I concur. But I cannot really get the question if not in the sense that he wants direct access to file objiects rather than building up the paths from the string file names.

Comment: well he wasn't very clear on what he wants to do and why he needs that, I guess lets leave it here and wait for feedback :D

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all what does it mean to collect it? If you need the file names it is already there for you in an array of String[] which you get from directory.list() method. If you want the full names you can use listFiles() method which returns a File[] and each file has getAbsolutePath() method.  Something like:

```
     for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
         System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```